# Why am I getting a "disciplined convex programming" error when using cvxpy?

Tags: python, cvxpy

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

n = 3
PP = cp.Variable((n,n),"PP")
KK = [[2,1,3],[1,2,1],[3,1,2]]
s = np.array([[.1, .4, .5]]).T
t = np.array([[.4, .2, .4]]).T
e = np.ones((n,1))
x = PP.T@e - s
y = PP@e - t
for b in range(1,21):
    obj = (1/4/b) * (cp.quad_form(x,KK) + cp.quad_form(y,KK)) - cp.trace(KK@PP) 
    prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(obj),[PP>=0,cp.sum(PP)==1])
    obj=prob.solve()
    print("status:",prob.status)
    print("obj:",obj)
    print(PP.value)
```

When I run this, I get

```
cvxpy.error.DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
The objective is not DCP. Its following subexpressions are not:
QuadForm(PP.T * [[1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]] + -[[0.1]
 [0.4]
 [0.5]], [[2. 1. 3.]
 [1. 2. 1.]
 [3. 1. 2.]])
```

I don't see why I'm getting this error when my matrix KK is clearly PSD. Why is this happening?

Duplicate here at
https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/34657/34383

Comment: This is a mathematical question and it belongs on SciComp SE.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I didn't even know SciComp SE existed.

Comment: It is easier if there's Mathjax before any code is shown. SciComp supports it, unlike SO. Oh, BTW, there's a CVXPY tag at SciComp.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please delete this question. Cross-posting is a bit rude.

Comment: Ok sure. Is there a way to merge the posts? The answer here is helpful.

Comment: You should have deleted as soon as you got an answer on SciComp. Such is the etiquette. Just post a link in each linking to the other.

Comment: Yeah -- I just woke up. Sorry.

Comment: Well, next time please cross-link the two questions, so that people do not invest time answering the same. In this case, their investment was not too substantial, but it could be much worse. Then you can go sleep, and if people miss the cross-links, it's not your responsibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I spoke too soon. Your matrix `KK` is not PSD (it has an eigenvalue -1). For people who see this issue with a matrix that should mathematically be PSD, I've left my original answer below.

Your matrix likely is likely, numerically, not quite PSD, even though mathematically it is. This is a limitation with CVXPY's quad form atom (that we may try to address later).

For now, you can take a (matrix) square root `sqrt_K` of K (using, eg, [scipy.linalg.sqrtm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.sqrtm.html)), and replace the `quad_form` atom with `cp.sum_squares(sqrt_K @ y)`.